# images display in jsp from servlet

Tags: java, image, jsp, servlets

I have uploaded images to server machine folder like c:images.
for this i have written "web.xml"`<context-param> 
    <description>Location to display uploaded file</description> 
    <param-name>file-display</param-name> 
    <param-value>
         C:/images/
     </param-value> 
</context-param>`

it is uploading perfectly well.
Now i need to display those images in a jsp with   `<img src=""/>`  tag.

i am finding the path using

```
filepath =  getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-display");
```

in servlet
and also attached image name. 
but how to represent in jsp with"      `<img src=""/>`       " tag.
is there another way to diplay images in jsp from server location folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the `ServletContext` in jsp using the predefined `application` variable:

```
application.getInitParameter("file-display");
```

If you are using Servlet API 3.0 (for EL 2.2, which supports calling methods in expressions) you can do:

```
${application.getInitParameter("file-display")}
```

Comment: thank you @micha, but i am not getting, can you send sample code.